# Detalhes com @Autowired e objeto do tipo Down

Tags: java, jpa, spring

Está havendo um conflito de conceitos comigo.

Tenho aqui um service chamado: `AtividadeService`

Têm algumas linhas que me chamam atenção:

```
import com.dendetech.entity.Atividade;
```

Por que importar a entity? Se só serve para o `AtividadeRepository`?

```
@Service
public class AtividadeService {

    @Autowired
    private AtividadeRepository atividadeRepository;

    private AtividadeDAO atividadeRepository = new AtividadeDAO();
```

Por que um novo objeto do tipo `AtividadeDown`, se já tem `@Autowired`?

(Restante omitido).

Answer (score 2):

De fato, isto aqui não está fazendo muito sentido:

```
@Autowired
private AtividadeRepository atividadeRepository;

private AtividadeDAO atividadeRepository = new AtividadeDAO();
```

Aliás, nem passaria na compilação, visto que você está declarando dois objetos diferentes com o mesmo nome dentro do escopo de uma mesma classe.

Outra coisa é que provavelmente você esteja fazendo alguma confusão de conceitos. Ou você usa um repositório, ou usa uma DAO. Repositórios são entidades que trabalham a nível de coleção. DAOs são entidades que trabalham a nível de tecnologia de banco de dados.

Além disso, a diferença entre DAO (*Data Access Object*) e DAL (*Data Access Layer*) não é apenas de uma letra: DAO é o objeto que faz parte de uma DAL. Normalmente, tanto a DAO quanto um repositório devolvem objetos do tipo DTO (*Data Transfer Object*).

Tendo isto entendido, podemos passar para o `@Autowired`.

`@Autowired` é a anotação para [Injeção de Dependência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_depend%C3%AAncia). Ela indica ao *framework* que o objeto marcado vai ser gerenciado pelo *framework* (seu ciclo de vida inteiro). Faz sentido para um `Service`, mas não faz muito sentido para uma entidade, visto que normalmente uma entidade (na maioria das vezes) é um  objeto anêmico que não requer gerenciamento do ciclo de vida (definição de DTO).

Portanto, para este caso, acho que seria interessante remover a declaração da DAO.

Comment: Não faz nenhum sentido `@Autowired` para entidades, pelo menos não consigo achar um contexto que faça. Já cometi esse erro grotesco, obviamente os estados da entidade era compartilhado entre todos os usuários.

Comment: @DanielaMorais Acho que essa pergunta é um caso de confusão completa de conceitos :)